# Unipaas extracting a XML

Tags: xml-parsing

Is someone tried to extract XML to "Unipass" Programming Language? I've read a XML file then put it on a blob virtual, From there i want i get the data inside .

```
                    <patient>
            <name>
                <given>Henry</given>
                <family>Sovelen</family>
                <suffix>The 6th</suffix>
            </name>
            <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
            <birthTime value="19320924"/>
        </patient>
```

Can someone teach me how to get the value 'Henry' Using unipaas programming language and btw i also used .xsl for stylesheet for that one

Answer (score 1):

UniPaas (previously know as Magic, or eDeveloper, or xpa) is able to read XML directly. XML is one of data sources available for UniPaas; there are gateways for MSSQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL and finally ODBC (which covers pretty much all other sources).

Luckily for you, no need to install support for XML, it's in UniPaas by default.

Since you are new to UniPaas and data sources, I'd recommend to see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrcPOKz556Q).

Once you have XML connected, you can use APG (automatic program generator) feature to quickly generate simple export-import program.

I'd strongly advice to install "On-line" samples, in Chapter 14 you can find example for XML data (see image below).
[image]

Let me know if you need more detail. UniPaas is really powerful tool, but it's "strange kind of animal" and can be confusing at the start.